# How to decipher a string in NodeJS that is encrypted in CryptoJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cryptojs

My client-side code:

```
data.username = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(user.username, "password");
data.password = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(user.password, "password");
```

When I send 'data' to the express.js server, like so:

```
var user = req.body;
var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes256', "password");
var decrypted = decipher.update(user.username, 'hex', 'utf-8');
decrypted += decipher.final('utf-8');
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: DecipherInit error
at new Decipher (crypto.js:368:17)
at Object.Decipher (crypto.js:365:12)
```

Comment: Here are some similar questions and answers: [Decrypting AES256 with node.js returns wrong final block length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21292142/608639), [Nodejs decrypt using crypto error wrong final block length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23111388/608639), [Getting error wrong final block length while decrypting AES256](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32038267/608639), [Decrypt file in Node.js encrypted using OpenSSL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44482151/608639), [What's wrong with node.js crypto decipher?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12219499/608639)

Answer (score 0):

CryptoJS' `encrypt` function with a password uses the same `EVP_BytesToKey` function node.js' `createCipher`, with the important difference that CryptoJS uses a random salt to derive whereas [node does not](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipher_algorithm_password) (emphasis mine):

> Note: createCipher derives keys with the OpenSSL function EVP_BytesToKey with the digest algorithm set to MD5, one iteration, and **no salt**.

Either you directly use CryptoJS in node which is possible, because CryptoJS doesn't have any dependencies, or you do the key derivation yourself on both ends and use `crypto.createCipheriv`. If you do the former, you would have to additionally pass the salts of the username and password encryptions to node.

Note that `data.username` is the CryptoJS cipherParams object which contains the salt and the IV, but when you convert this to string with `data.username.toString()`, the salt is not included anymore, but the IV is. This is not the `data` that you would put into the node.js functions. Send `data.username.ciphertext` instead.

Comment: [OpenSSL 1.1.0c changed the digest algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39637388/608639) used in some internal components. Formerly, MD5 was used, and 1.1.0 switched to SHA256. Be careful the change is not affecting you in both `EVP_BytesToKey` and commands like `openssl enc`.