# Hide error from executing nodejs command in bash script

Tags: node.js, bash

I have a bash script that executes some node commands (node file.js).
If there is an error in file.js is there a way to stop it going onto the terminal?

I have tried exec 2>/dev/null before the command

I have just entered characters into the script to produce an error to show the type of error I want to hide.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could use `process.on('uncaughtException',...)`  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761475/node-js-catching-errors-so-script-doesnt-break

Comment: Works great thanks :)