# Node: never use try-catch?

Tags: node.js, exception, callback, try-catch

I'm writing a data processing system in Node.js.

Pieces of data are user provided or come from outside sources, so

- they can be malformed in various ways;
- they can be ambiguous;
- they can be contradictory to each other.

In those cases I generally want to alert user about it and then:

- if the system is used in interactive mode (i.e. data is entered in REPL) the processing should stop, suggest some actions and wait for user's decision.
- if it runs in batch mode (i.e. data comes from files, web services or similar sources) I want to continue processing discarding this pieces of information.

Of course the method of alerting user also depends on mode.

I thought that exceptions are right solution for this kind of problem, because:

- malformed or contradictory data *should be an exception*;
- this way code for exceptional behavior will be visibly separated from usual flow;
- I'll be able to bubble exceptions to higher level, on which I can decide what exactly to do with it.

So I started to look for guides and found two relevant things:

1. This comment by @Raynos [Node.js Best Practice Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling#comment8815552_7313005) ;
2. http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2010/01/25/don-t-use-try-catch/.

The former is without further explanation. The later I understand, but I think it's not my case.

How would you address this? I'm looking for general approach, not necessarily platform or language specific... or is there anything especially evil in JavaScript try-catch?

Comment: I think you should rephrase the title/question to avoid closing.

Comment: @ShaggyFrog: I guess you are right. But man, some guys are quick - before I managed to open this question for edition to change title, ControlAltDel did it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that try { } catch { } finally { } has limited usefulness in standard node, and error handling can be problematic.

However In a project I was recently on, I used these node modules: Fibers, Fibers-Promise in a way where effectively, I could do something akin to Thread.join on async callbacks, and making it possible to use node in a procedural, rather than functional style.

There are tradeoffs. Fibers / all co-routine libraries modify node's core code, making it impossible to use on the front end. But depending on your purposes, you might want to look into this.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll be using try-catch only on synchronous code. That is that there won't be any async functions call inside try block.

Comment: Okay I think you should be fine then

Comment: Thank you. I'm still hoping for some guides and tips from others, so I won't mark your answer as accepted yet. Also those modules that you mention are very interesting. Especially fibers-promise looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

If it is DATA that you are handling, you might try to think of the app as a message transport.

In this pattern, there cannot be anything to catch, any data that is not understood has a valid message returned to the user - a message saying that the data was invalid.

That way you are not trying to use your code to catch a data error - not something that is good to do.

You don't really need a special library to handle this, it is as much a thought exercise as anything. Actually, a "Model" handler (think MVC) would do the job nicely. Alternatively, you simply need to filter out any really bad data (zero or excessively long for example) before passing it to a parser function - if the parser fails to fully understand the data, default to returning an error message to the user.