# Error handling exclusive queue subscription in node-amqp (node.js)

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp, cloudamqp, node-amqp

When you subscribe to an exclusive queue (only one consumer allowed at a time), node-amqp throws an exception when the queue is oversubscribed (already has a consumer).

- I've tried using the .on("error",cb) syntax.
- I've tried error domains (node 0.10.0)
- Try/catch obviously didn't work

Here's my subscription line, but it's nothing special:

```
queue.subscribe({ack: true, prefetchCount: 1, exclusive: exclusive}, cbExecute).addCallback((ok) -> listeners[type] = ok.consumerTag);
```

You get an unhandled exception thrown when queue is in use:

```
ACCESS_REFUSED - queue 'respQ' in vhost 'brkoacph' in exclusive use
```

Looking inside node-amqp I see that they implement an independent task queue inside the module so that when the error occurs, the task is running in an independent context.

Is there any work-around/fix? ...or am I just doing something wrong?

Comment: I think you get a better answer with the core developers: https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp/issues

Comment: Node.js uncaught errors handling explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling And it works for me with your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is to catch the errors in the `AMQP connection`. 
As you mentioned, `node-amqp` captures errors in a different context, but you can listen to then on the connection:

```
yourConnectionVar.on( 'error', function(err) {
  //do something
  console.log('An error occurred' + err);
});
```

I hope this helps.

Cheers!

Comment: I think this is as good as we're going to get without node-amqp surgery. Thank you.