# Node.js uncaught exceptions

Tags: linux, node.js, uncaught-exception

according to many articles, the best way to handle uncaught exceptions in a node.js app is let the process crash and than restart it. This avoids to have our application in a unstable state.
I think it can be done with an external process like a watchdog (sometimes called angel process). 
What is the best way to do this in a linux system? At first glance a bash script checking the node process state every n seconds could be a possible solution.
Thank in advance, any suggestion will be really appreciated.

[Node.js Best Practice Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling)

http://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/

http://debuggable.com/posts/node-js-dealing-with-uncaught-exceptions:4c933d54-1428-443c-928d-4e1ecbdd56cb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a handful of solutions like the watchdog/angel process you mention. The one you most often hear thrown around is "forever". It's available via npm.

To install, just: `npm install -g forever`

Then when you want to run your app: `forever app.js` instead of `node app.js`

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully used [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/), I think it fits your purpose very well. It's not node-specific and you can use it virtually with anything that won't detach from the console.

And with the [events](http://supervisord.org/events.html#events) feature, it gives a nice flexible tool for all kinds of scenarios.