# What is the best way to catch ReferenceError or TypeError in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the best way to catch ReferenceError or TypeError in node.js? I was wondering if I can prevent node.js servers from being crashed by such errors...

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js Best Practice Exception Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling)

Comment: `try` to `catch` them.

Comment: Okay. I will do this. That link also gave a lot of ideas catching exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exception handler. One is the [process.on(...)](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)
Another way is, use try-catch structure for critical statements. And of course checks all of data which come from outside of code, for example database, or file, or userinput.

```
var obj = require('./my-safe-json.json');
var anotherProp = obj.prop.anotherProp; // possible reference error
```

You can it be safer:

```
var obj = require('./my-safe-json.json');
if(obj && typeof obj.prop == 'object'){
    var anotherProp = obj.prop.anotherProp;
}else{
    //handle wrong json
}
```