# Acitvate express/node error handler on user code exception

Tags: node.js, express

I have code as follows:

app.js

```
app.use(app.router)
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.render(errorPage)
})

app.get('/', function(req,res,next) {
  module1.throwException(function{ ... });
});
```

module1.js

```
exports.thowException = function(callback) {
       // this throws a TypeError exception.
       // follwoing two lines are getting executed async
       // for simplicity I removed the async code
       var myVar = undefined;
       myVar['a'] = 'b'
       callback()
}
```

With the exception in module1.js, my node prcoess dies. Instead I wanted to render error page.

I tried try ... catch in app.get(..), it did not help.

How can I do this??

Comment: is there a way for me to return 404 from process.on(...)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `try ... catch` with asynchronous code. [In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling?lq=1) you can find some basic principles for error handling in node.js. In your situation you should return error as a first parameter of your callback from your module instead of throwing it and next call your Error handler. Because your error handling function is just after app.route handler, you should also check for Not Found error if any of your route doesn't match. Next code is very simplified example.

app.js

```js
app.use(app.router)
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  if (err) {
    res.render(errorPage); // handle some internal error
  } else {
    res.render(error404Page); // handle Not Found error
  }
})

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  module1.notThrowException(function(err, result) {
    if (err) {
      next(new Error('Some internal error'));
    }
    // send some response to user here
  });
});
```

module1.js

```
exports.notThrowException = function(callback) {
  var myVar = undefined;
  try {
    myVar['a'] = 'b';
  } catch(err) {
    callback(err)
  }

  // do some other calculations here 

  callback(null, result); // report result for success
}
```

Comment: I was pretty much doing all of it what the post elaborates and you suggested. I was just hoping to catch all UNEXPECTED exceptions before it reaches process.on(..). Specifically, any bug introduced by USER (my) code running asynchronously. So that I can return error page.

Comment: is there a way for me to return 404 from process.on(...)

Comment: You can caught all UNEXPECTED exeption using

Comment: You can caught all UNEXPECTED exeptions using process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) { ... ); or using domains. But the safest way to handle unexpected exceptions is restart whole process.