# how avoid nodejs crashes

Tags: javascript, node.js

There must be a way to prevent crashes in every mistake. I'm using this:

```
try
{
    // blabla
    throw "Error";
}
catch(err)
{
    self.Error(err);
}
```

but I can not be continuously capturing them

Comment: For synchronous operations, `try..catch` should work fine. But, since most Node APIs are asynchronous, they won't complete within the same call stack as `try..catch`. These will usually offer an `'error'` event [you can add a listener to](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_on_event_listener). But, it depends on the API. See "[Node.js Best Practice Exception Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling)" for more.

Comment: Or, the `Error` will just be passed as an argument to a callback (`function (err, arg0)`). `throw` statements aren't actually all that common with Node.js due to the asynchronous focus.

Comment: Nodejs crashes? Or you mean, how can I ignore errors/exceptions in my code? In your example, it looks like you are in control of throwing the exception and handling it. It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve.