# nodejs uncaught exceptions after sending reponse

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express, exception, restify

I've a restify server that get requests from a client with some parameters to run a long process.

so, after initializing some attributes and some checks, the service returns a json to the client (and start processing **asynchronusly**). then the client can monitor the process via log files on sockets.

The problem is any exception ***before***

```
res.send(jsonObject)
```

can be caught by

```
process.on('uncaughtException'...
```

but any exception ***after*** sending the response can't be caught!!!

regardless that handling exceptions this way isn't the best way and tailing on sockets isn't so good

I want to be able to catch the later exceptions that may occur after sending response to the client!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling) post regarding exception handling. When an error bubbles up to uncaughtException it puts the process in an unknown state. If you'd instead like to isolate these exceptions then consider using [domains](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) to wrap your logic safely.

> **Per NodeJs documentation:**  "Note that uncaughtException is a very
>   crude mechanism for exception handling and may be removed in the
>   future.
>
> Don't use it, use domains instead. If you do use it, restart your
>   application after every unhandled exception!
>
> Do not use it as the node.js equivalent of On Error Resume Next. An
>   unhandled exception means your application - and by extension node.js
>   itself - is in an undefined state. Blindly resuming means anything
>   could happen.
>
> Think of resuming as pulling the power cord when you are upgrading
>   your system. Nine out of ten times nothing happens - but the 10th
>   time, your system is bust.
>
> You have been warned."

Comment: yes, I know it's not recommended to use it, but the problem here is general. what happens to the stack after calling res.send() ? so that exceptions can't be caught?