# Node JS Crypto: wrong password while decrypt

Tags: javascript, node.js, encryption, error-handling

I'm encrypting/decrypting a string using the following functions:

```
function encrypt(text, pswrd){
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher(algorithm,pswrd),
      crypted = cipher.update(text,'utf8','hex');
      crypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return crypted;
}

function decrypt(text, pswrd){
  var decipher = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm,pswrd),
      dec = decipher.update(text,'hex','utf8');
      dec += decipher.final('utf8');
  return dec;
}
```

The password is being asked using [inquirer](https://github.com/SBoudrias/Inquirer.js/blob/master/examples/password.js), so the user input a password to encrypt and then should use the same to decrypt.

Everything works while the password matches, but the problem is when the password is wrong. I can't find a callback/method to handle the error that the console outputs then a decryption fails because of the wrong password. the terminal shows:

```
? Use same password: *
p�pP��X�B
��=�a�_��b��EyX��7�����X�y�����+�Rr�<��΅W��B�������am4r���+��v�
readline.js:924
            throw err;
            ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 
    at Object.parse (native)
```

How can I handle this error when a wrong password is used to decrypt?

Comment: Have you tried `try {...} catch(e){...}` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js Best Practice Exception Handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling)

Comment: You don't normally get automatic integrity checking using ciphers like that. Which algorithm are you using?

Comment: @Phil_1984_ it's `algorithm = 'aes-256-ctr'`

Comment: You should look in to authenticated encryption or using an existing encryption library that handles authentication so you can catch incorrect password errors properly.

Answer (score -1):

We have the same inquiry, I hope this help, What I did solution is.

cipher decryption has no callback for check password, but I made it simple, I create a token validator (which is also encrypted from cipher) every-time I received a data(which is also encrypted in cypher).
token & "data" are encrypted in same password, if token(decryption from correct-password) is validated from my tokenValidator(hmac or web-token). then "data" is now valid to process from my server