# Nodejs never die?

Tags: node.js, forever

I use forever to keep a nodejs instance up.

When there is an error, the server stops working and the log shows a javascript exception.
(for example, a get request returns nothing when the server code expected it to).

Is there a way for node to NEVER stop running? To simply "look past" the error?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look here: [Node.js Best Practice Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling)

that's the way to handle exceptions:

```js
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  console.log(err);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

The only safe way to prevent Node from *ever* stopping is to write perfect, bug-free code.

But once you've resigned yourself to the occasional uncaught exception, the safe and recommended approach is to crash and restart with an external monitor.

> Unhandled exceptions inherently mean that an application is in an undefined state. Attempting to resume application code without properly recovering from the exception can cause additional unforeseen and unpredictable issues.

-- https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception