# node js uncaughtException sends empty object in callback

Tags: node.js

I have set up an `uncaughtException` event listener in node js:

```
process.on('uncaughtException', function (err) {
    console.log('uncaughtException: ');
    console.log(err);

    process.exit(1);
});
```

To test it I tried the following. At one time:

```
callNonExistantFunction();
```

And at another:

```
throw new Error('test error');
```

In both cases, the exceptions were caught, but the value of the `err` parameter in the callback function was an empty object: `{}`. Is there any way to get the details of the error? I'm working on a Windows machine if it matters.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve by capturing the uncaught exception but reading this article may help https://shapeshed.com/uncaught-exceptions-in-node/

Comment: cause it's callback function i guess
more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling