# node server crashing on uncaught exception

Tags: node.js, express, npm

what is the best strategy to make node server not crash on uncaught exceptions?
I have a web application in node. Whenever some uncaught error happens , server fails completely.we have to go to production soon.So this cannot happen in production.

How can we handle this?

Comment: There is a detailed answer already here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling

Comment: Thanks..are there any new practices developed over time?

Comment: Refer to this document from Joyent https://www.joyent.com/node-js/production/design/errors