# Heroku, app is crashing (H10 error), how to prevent this?

Tags: node.js, heroku, crash

I have a Node.js app hosted on Heroku. Sometimes, there is insignifiant JS errors (variable not defined, because a 3rd-party API error), then the App crashes with H10 error, and all the future requests are crashing also (even a GET on an .jpg). Yea, my app crashed and I have to reboot it manually.

My question is, how to avoid this kind of situation ? How to reboot the app automatically after a crash ? Or maybe how to prevent the app to crash. I cannot prevent all the millions possible cases as I'm depending on multiple 3rd-party API that can change the response body at any time...

Thank you!

Comment: important rule : handle nulls, empty or even undefined, like in JS, before using them in any calls, or filling data from those variables.

Comment: seems duplicate of the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling