# Error handling with try..catch in Node.js

Tags: node.js, error-handling, callback, response, http-status-codes

I am wondering if in the following scenario am I am handling the right way  the **error** and what is that I should return on **error**? Can you return **statusCode** on anything or only on **response**?

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    if (err) {
        new Error({
            status: "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
        })
    }
    let filepath = './public/images/'
    cb(null, filepath)
},
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    if (err) {
        new Error({
            status: "INTERNAL SERVER ERROR"
        })
    }
    let ext = file.originalname.split(".").pop();
    let filename = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + ext
    //console.log(ext);
    cb(null, filename);
}
```

})

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Node.js Best Practice Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use status codes only on the response object.

For more details read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).

Try reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling) once.

---

The answer to your **updated code**:

You can send the error in the callback object.
Read more about [callback here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function).

The callback takes two params:

1. Error
2. Data

I will update your code below:

Updated Code:

```
    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, cb) {
            if (err) {
                cb(err, null);
            }
            let filepath = './public/images/'
            cb(null, filepath)
        },
        filename: function(req, file, cb) {
            if (err) {
                cb(err, null);
            }
            let ext = file.originalname.split(".").pop();
            let filename = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.' + ext
            //console.log(ext);
            cb(null, filename);
        }
    })
```

This is how you ideally handle errors with the callback.

Try this and check if it works.

Comment: i edited my code according those answers. is this right now or do I need to handle at all in this case?

Comment: Okay, tell me this, you have incoming **req** object, correct?

Then you must be having **res** object for that **req** object.

And you can send the error in the **cb** instead of creating 

"new Error...."

I would update my answer if you could answer my above questions

Comment: I would update your code in the answer, check it out.