# How to handle twilio Errors that crash nodejs

Tags: node.js, twilio

Using the twilio nodejs api crashes node when an error is thrown.
For example if the room already exists..

> /home/web/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:876
>       throw error; Error: Room exists

Try catch does not help.
Tried wrapping it in a promise, no luck.
Tried to first fetch the room, but it crashes in the same way if the room does not exist.
Tried to retrieve a list of all in-progress rooms, but it stalls forever. I can get a list of all completed rooms but I need to check in-progress ones.
Either way crashing node is no good, need to be able to handle these eventualities.

```js
    exports.createBackendRoom = function (roomname, callback) {
        try {
            client.video.rooms.create({uniqueName: roomname})
            .then(function(room) {
                console.log(room);
                callback(true);
            }).done();
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e);
            callback(false);
        }
    }
```

Unable to handle the errors..

/home/web/node_modules/twilio/node_modules/q/q.js:876
    throw error;
Error: Room exists

How can I gracefully handle these?

Comment: maybe this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling or you can call `callback(true)` on error and handle the error on the other ways

Comment: Thanks, that kinda helps, if I put it in a domain, then at least it doesn't crash the application.. eg. d.run(function(){ client.video.rooms.create( ...  But is that the best solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Try catch does not help.

This is because error is being thrown by asynchronous operation. `Try-catch` will handle the error thrown by synchronous operation. To handle asynchronous errors, add a `catch(err=>{})` block

```
exports.createBackendRoom = function (roomname, callback) {
  client.video.rooms.create({uniqueName: roomname})
    .then(function (room) {
      console.log(room);
      callback(true);
    }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err); // handle error
    callback(false);
  }).done();
};
```