# Can this piece of code theoretically stop a Node JS app from crashing?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling

```
process
  .on("uncaughtException", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .on("unhandledRejection", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
  .on("uncaughtExceptionMonitor", (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Would this piece of code stop a Node JS process from crashing even without try and catch blocks for the line of code to let out a promise rejection to explicitly crash the code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling

Comment: It would stop it from crashing, but it may be in an indeterminate state (files left open, resources leaked, etc...) so this is not a useful design strategy for just continuing as if nothing happened.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js Best Practice Exception Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling)