# Redis connection to x.x.x.x:6379 failed - write ECONNRESET. NodeJS GCP Standard Environment

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, redis, http-status-code-502

The redis get calls sometimes fails with the following error. Once this happens, as a follow through, many of the requests fail/timeout intermittently with a 502 status.

```
{ Error: Redis connection to X.X.X.X:6379 failed - write ECONNRESET
        at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:78:25)
        at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:73:3)
        at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:714:5)
        at Socket._write (net.js:726:8)
        at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
        at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
        at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
        at RedisClient.write (/workspace/node_modules/redis/index.js:949:43)
        at RedisClient.internal_send_command (/workspace/node_modules/redis/index.js:885:14)
        at RedisClient.internal_send_command_trace [as internal_send_command] (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/trace-agent/build/src/plugins/plugin-redis.js:91:50)
        at RedisClient.get (/workspace/node_modules/redis/lib/commands.js:46:25)
        at Promise (internal/util.js:274:30)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at RedisClient.get (internal/util.js:273:12)
        at ConversationQueueServices.startTimeoutToClearQueueForVisitor (/workspace/ls/Services/ConversationQueueServices.js:306:57)
        at PeoplesService.onVisitorSubscriberLeft (/workspace/ls/Services/PeoplesService.js:51:31)
        at app.post (/workspace/app.js:196:27)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at next (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
        at Route.dispatch (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
        at /workspace/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22 errno: 'ECONNRESET', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'write' }
```

From the looks of it, ECONNRESET indicates the connection is closed by redis instance.  There is no surge of traffic of any sort. cpu, memory and number of connections are as usual.

Will moving to updated redis npm client may help? Currently using 3.0.2 redis client version

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this link for a possible solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17245881/how-do-i-debug-error-econnreset-in-node-js/17798353#17798353

Comment: Is there any proxy or load-balancer in between your redis-server and your node servers?

Comment: Karthikeyan, let me know if the answer was helpful, or are you looking form some other information.

Comment: Hi @VaidehiJamankar. Please give me sometime. I will get back to you on this before this week.

Comment: hi @LeibaleEidelman. GCP has nginx for load balancing for the node servers

Answer (score 2):

`ECONNRESET` error is thrown usually when the other end of the connection which could be TCP connected node that is communicating with the server or calling out and the socket timeout results in no response received which results in the sender closing it with the timeout exception handling type.
You can try to add [retries](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/retries) or increase the [timeout](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/request-timeout) for the redis connection configurations.
Try running through this tutorial which might be  helpful for troubleshooting the [Redis Setup](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/setting-up-redis).

Please check a similar example with details [node-js-best-practice-exception-handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310521/node-js-best-practice-exception-handling).